# Any tutorials instructing how to use Maven artifacts of Eclipse in a standalone manner?

Tags: eclipse, maven, osgi, swt, p2

As far as I know, with the exception of SWT, most Maven artifacts of Eclipse rely heavily on an OSGi environment and thus cannot decouple with Eclipse and cannot be used in a standalone manner. If striving so, you'll end up with implementing a desperate list of interface methods that eventually may deviate from your mission focus and may not work at all. I'm not sure why Tycho needs to straddle and pull artifacts from both Maven and P2 repositories. Sometimes I just want to go without Eclipse IDE. I'd like to use part of Eclipse classes as data models and even part of the methods to get needed data, instead of writing my own code to parse such files as `p2.index`, `content.jar`, and `artifacts.jar`. Artifacts of SWT on Maven are able to go without Eclipse.

Most online tutorials teach you how to write plugins and RCPs inside Eclipse IDE but how about developing a standalone application parsing P2 repositories, identifying dependencies and fetching needed artifacts and features in my own way in place of the P2 way, with the help of dependencies from Maven and built-in Java libraries? Are there any systematic tutorials or documentations instructing so?

Comment: That would be enormously difficult. What you can do is write "headless" Eclipse apps which don't use the GUI.

Comment: Tycho is a Maven plugin and thus not an Eclipse-based application doing P2 things: https://github.com/eclipse-tycho/tycho What is the benefit of without Eclipse/OSGi? With OSGi, things become more scalable, faster, and less memory consuming.

Comment: @howlger I'm sorry but there are processes I tried hard to intercept, namely the P2 provision processes, so as to streamline my using experience of Eclipse. With a few modifications I can significantly and permanently speed up online provision speed. Currently P2 does not officially support my informal way. The provision speed is the narrowest bottleneck driving me crazy. Mini-experiments using platform runtime binary have proven my conception viable.

Comment: @howlger My program needs to get away with the heavy infrastructure of an OSGi environment to maintain minimal and flexible. Anything involving current P2 mechanisms will significantly slow down the network performance. Maven repository is the alternative way I can utilize with confidence. Building a customized P2 bundles from source fails because still it involves P2, and has harsh incompatibility with the version of bundles of Eclipse I'm using. I have little control over P2 within Eclipse environment.

Comment: @howlger I'm not so familiar with the definition of Tycho but I am clear what I try to achieve. Observing Tycho I saw the whole processes pulling artifacts from both Maven (walks like a duck) and P2 (quacks like a duck) repositories so I assumed Tycho a duck (typing). Of course I abandoned Tycho later after realizing that I still had little control over the P2 processes. I'm now doing provision in a pure Maven and Java way.

Comment: @greg-449 A "headless" Eclipse app can't intercept what I want to intercept (P2) so I'm giving up on this idea. I'm sorry.

Answer (score 0):

> Sometimes I just want to go without Eclipse IDE. I'd like to use part of Eclipse classes as data models and even part of the methods to get needed data, instead of writing my own code to parse such files as `p2.index`, `content.jar`, and `artifacts.jar`.

Yes, you can. However, as @greg-449 put it, "That would be enormously difficult." The reason is that these classes are loaded with their respective ClassLoader (container) associated with the package where they are in, which is to say, the class of a Maven artifact of Eclipse a plain Java program initializes will be viewed by the JVM as different with the counterpart in the running OSGi environment, despite their identical full name, so casting is not possible. You'll need to use reflection mechanism of Java to manipulate OSGi classes to get data or do jobs in a plain Java program.
It will be a brain twister, since you are going to go without advanced grammar check from the IDE, and write lots of additional lines of codes to mimic the original features. The classes you deal with all the time are Class, Method, Parameter, etc.. The exception you deal with all the time is NullPointerException. You'll get crazy with which package the class is in, which ClassLoader to use, and how to construct parameters for the class constructor / methods to work.